# Post build event fired before files are created in bin folder

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, msbuild, post-build-event, web.config-transform

I've written a Post Build script that copies the Web.config file generated for different environments in the bin folder to the main Web.config file.

For example:
After a successful build of the Project the transformed config file for say stage environment is generated in *"bin/configs/stage/web.config"* location.

My script is copying this file to main *Web.config* of the project so as to run the project locally also in the selected target environment.

Problem:
If I delete the Configs folder, and let it to be generate once again the build is completed, my POST Build script fires up before the file is generated and breaks the build.

How can I fire this event after all files are successfully generated/created in the bin folder?

Any suggestion or solutions will be of great help!